# Online Algorithm to Process Percent of Requests

Tags: algorithm

The catch is that not all requests should be processed. To formulate a little more clearly:

Suppose you have a target ratio r, and the algorithm sees either "op" or "nop" at each iteration. The goal is to decide whether to process the "op"s (let's call a processed op a "pop") such that

#pop / (#op + #nop) ~= r

I think the naive approach of just tracking the above the ratio and making sure it stays within reasonable bounds would work ok in practice, so I'm more interested in whether this a well-known problem or if there is some code I could re-use here.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the problem description? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Assuming the stream is big enough, w.h.p you'll get pretty close, if you simply do a [bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial) for each entry with the desired ratio as the "success" probability - or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @amit I guess that would work pretty well if we wanted #pop / #op ~= r. The existence of #nop's changes things a bit, I think; the extent to which they matter probably depends a lot on how we want to model the arrival of ops vs. nops. (Are the choices made i.i.d. from some known distribution? i.i.d. but from some unknown distribution? adversarially? If choices are made adversarially, what constraints does the adversary have to observe? etc.)

Comment: @templatetypedef: What is unclear about the question?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: I think its safe to assume the arrival of ops vs nops are fairly random, definitely not chosen adversarially. The context is a map reduce job that reads a bunch of data, filters some of it (nops), and chooses some to process (ops), which the goal of actually processing only a fixed % of the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that whether any given operation is a nop or not is decided iid with probability `p`, then one thing you could do is choose to process each op iid with some probability `q`. The goal is that

```
r = P(pop)
  = P(pop|op)P(op) + P(pop|nop)P(nop)
  = qp + 0(1-p)
```

so we should choose `q = r/p`. Easy cheesy.

If `p` is not known, one can keep a running total of #op and #nop to estimate `p`; I recommend using Gaussian smoothing, so that you estimate `p = (#op + 1) / (#op + #nop + 1)`.

There is an obvious deterministic heuristic that will also work well: namely, if our running value for `#op/(#op+#nop)` is below `r`, process the next operation you see; otherwise, don't. This should produce quite good results for `r`; however, it has a strong downside that the decision to process an operation or not is deterministic and depends only on how many previous operations we've processed. In particular, if there is a correlation between how many operations you've seen so far and the *content* of the operation -- for example, certain particularly interesting operations are less likely to appear shortly after a long string of nops, or any other such "temporal correlation" between operations -- this will bias your results in subtle and difficult-to-detect ways. I'm guessing that you cannot really know whether such patterns exist in the data without processing the entire data set (which is presumably too much work). Therefore I recommend a probabilistic algorithm instead.

Comment: The "naive approach" I mentioned in the question is the deterministic heuristic you suggested, which I've already implemented and had success with. I hadn't considered the probabilistic approach though... It does seem like it would work better, although maybe a tad harder to implement. I'll stick with the simple version until it breaks... Thanks!

Comment: @dzelemba The implementation of the probabilistic version should be pretty simple. Pick a number uniformly at random between 0 and #op (inclusive). If that number is less than `r * (#op + #nop + 1)`, process the operation; otherwise don't.